# One child div must overflow the other must not

Tags: html, css, user-interface, sass

[image]

Here the red box is the parent div which does not have any overflow property set. The orange and gray boxes are its children.
What I want is to know is whether it is possible for one of the child to overflow the other to not?

```css
.rootdiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  border: solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rootdiv .not-overflow {
  border: dashed;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

.rootdiv .must-overflow {
  border: dashed;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
    <div class="not-overflow">
      This must get chopped.
    </div>
    <div class="must-overflow">
      This must overflow.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that overflow is relative to its children so it's either one or the other if you want to only have one parent division.

[image]

So this effect is unachivable with just one wrapper division. however when you add a third one its pretty simple. take a look at the example

```css
.bigDiv {
  background: red;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.bigDiv div div {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  width: 75vw;
  border: 3px dashed black;
}

.divOne {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chop {
  background: orange;
}
.overflow {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigDiv">

  <div class="divOne">
    <div class="chop">
      <p>this must get chopped</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTwo">
    <div class="overflow">
      <p>this must overflow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the result [image]

Answer (score 2):

I added overflow for the main `<div>` and used `position:absolute` for the `.must-overflow` that should overflow:

```css
.rootdiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  border: solid;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.rootdiv .not-overflow {
  border: dashed;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

.rootdiv .must-overflow {
  border: dashed;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute ;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
    <div class="not-overflow">
      This must get chopped.
    </div>
    <div class="must-overflow">
      This must overflow.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the parent div had a position property set. Will it be possible then?

Comment: Position relative for the parent would make this code non-functional for your case, do you have such a case now?

Comment: I do yes. I want a certain child to overflow. A child set relative to its parent. But that parent has other elements which must not overflow.

Comment: Ok will check it now.

Comment: I have updated the question and set position for the parent div. thank you.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that was not included in the question before, but your solution is better than mine, how does your solution using pseudo element works? didn't use it much before

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space:nowrap` in both divs, and `overflow:hidden` in the one you want chopped.

See jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/23cry94b/

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element  with a big box-sahdow and can control the z-index then you can easily hide/unhide the overflow you want:

```css
.rootdiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding:3px;
  background: red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.rootdiv:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 calc(100vw + 100vh) #fff;
  z-index:0;
}

.rootdiv > div {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  margin:20px 0 0 20px;
  border: dashed;
}

.rootdiv .not-overflow {
  background: orange;
  z-index:-1; /* will not overflow */
}

.rootdiv .must-overflow {
  background: gray;
  z-index:1; /* will overflow */
}
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
    <div class="not-overflow">
      This must get chopped.
    </div>
    <div class="must-overflow">
      This must overflow.
    </div>
    <div class="not-overflow">
      This must get chopped.
    </div>
    <div class="must-overflow">
      This must overflow.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create parent divs with `width: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` where you want to hidden. For example:

```css
.rootdiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    border: solid;
    position: relative;
    /* overflow: hidden;*/
  }

  .rootdiv .not-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  }

/* NOTE: just transformed the original "not-overflow" from the question to "styles" */ 
  .styles {
    border: dashed;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
  }

/* end of changes */

  .rootdiv .must-overflow {
    border: dashed;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="rootdiv">
  <div class="not-overflow">
    <div class="styles">This must get chopped.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="must-overflow">This must overflow.</div>
</div>
```

Edit 1: You don't need to work with positions, but if you want, this solution won't bother you.